# Front right wheel making low pitch screeching when driving

Tags: brakes, tires, noise, wheels, cv-joint

Whenever I reverse at low speed at full lock the front right wheel makes a low pitch screech. The sounds is now starting to occur when driving forward. Tapping the break gets rid of the noise sometimes but it comes back pretty quick so not sure if related.

I've recently had the CV axles done but the other day I also used tyre shine and I'm worried some may have got on the brakes/rotor.

That car is a 1998 n15 Nissan Pulsar. Could this be the brakes or poor CV axle job?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: First thought is wheel bearing.

Comment: how does the brake pads look is it time to replace them? it sounds more like a brake problem and less likely a problem with the cv axle.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at the pads but I haven't heard any squealing from the brakes before. Do they usually make some noise before going bad?

Comment: I have had similar where a small stone is trapped by the caliper and rubs against the rotor: but not all the time. The noise it makes is disproportionate to the problem.

Comment: Stone between rotor and dust shield also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to post this but the issue was that the slider pin needed lubricating and was causing the break to not back off from the rotor. This accelerated the wear on the pads so a fresh dollop of lube for the slider pin and some new pads solved this issue!